# Ignore JsonTypeInfo in rest controller

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

Hi I have a class with field configuration:

```
     @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
            property = "@type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = XYZ, name = "XYZ"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ZYX, name = "ZYX")
    })
public class XZZ
```

I need to receive in Rest Controller *XZZ* without field @type but be able to have it in ObjectMapper automatically. 
I'm trying to avoid creating the same object, one to receive in restController and second to parse to JSON with @type. Of course XYZ and ZYX extends XZZ.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your XZZ class (or wherever the "@type" attribute exists), add the annotation:

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String type;
```

Comment: I've tried that but it won't help. Requests are still ignored.